# Unable to train pySpark SVM, labeled point issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, training-data

I am trying to turn an spark Dataframe to labeled point.
The Dataframe is named DF and looks like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
|step1|step2|step3|step4|step5|step6|step7|step8|step9|step10|class|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
|   14|   14|    0|   14|   14|    4|   11|   10|    0|     7|    1|
|   11|   10|   14|    0|   14|   18|   18|   14|    7|     7|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    7|    0|    7|     0|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|    7|    7|   14|   14|    0|    11|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    7|   14|     7|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    0|    7|     7|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    7|   14|     7|    1|
|   17|   14|    0|    7|    0|    0|   14|    7|    0|     7|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|    7|    7|   14|    7|   14|   14|     7|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    7|    7|     7|    1|
|    7|   14|   14|   14|   14|    0|   14|    7|    0|    14|    1|
|   14|   14|   14|   14|   14|    0|   14|    7|    7|     7|    1|
```

what I am trying to do, following the documentation, is:

```
(training, test) = DF.randomSplit([0.8,0.2])
print training
def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[:1])

trainLabeled = training.rdd.map(parsePoint)
model = SVMWithSGD.train(trainLabeled, iterations=100)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
```

Spark version 2.0.1

Comment: Hi, could you precise which Spark version you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seing your data, but an usual issue with `SVMWithSGD` comes from the label.

You need to use `LabeledPoint` (as you did) and ensure that first parameter is either 0.0 or 1.0. The error might come from `x[-1]` being another value (not 0 nor 1).

Could you check it?

Hope it helps,
pltrdy

---

**Edit (after seing data):**

Hem. Let's go back to basics: SVM (roughly) **"learns how to split data in two classes"** (this is not very formal, but lets take it for now). This being said, your dataset must be: a `X` matrix of shape `n x D` (`n` number of rows, `D` number of features), and a `y` matrix `n x 1` containing labels of data. Labels are binary usually denoted `{0, 1}` (or `{-1, 1}` which is more convenient for maths).
This is quite the "math" approach. Usually you have one `data` matrix which you split between `X` and `y` by "extracting" a column as the label. (all values in this column must be either 0, 1).

This being said, making long story short: SVM will classify your data on **two** classes.

The label (= classes, which value is either 0 or 1) can be seen as a two categories used to split your data. So you must have a column with only 0 or 1.

***For example*** if I build my movie dataset, I could set a column "do i like it?" with `label=1` if I like the film and `label=0` if i don't, then train my SVM to predict which movie I am supposed to like

I don't see in your data which column is the **label**. If you have more than 2 classes, SVM is not for you, you will have to take a look to multivariate classification (which is out of scope here, tell me if it is what you want).

I do guess that your objective isn't really clear to you. As an example, one will not train classification using ID column, this rarely makes sense. If I'm wrong, please explain what do you expect from your data. (you can also explain what columns refers).

```
pltrdy
```

Comment: thank you for that. I have added a screenshot of the data. So that means that the last column should be the first when trying to create the labeled points?

Comment: The label (which value is either 0 or 1) has to be seen as a "categorie" you want to split your data. So you must have a column with only 0 or 1. For example if I build my movie dataset, I could set a column "do i like it?" with label=1 if I like the film and label=0 if i don't, then train my SVM to predict which movie I am supposed to like.

Comment: yes, my bad. I am wrong in the implementation. I didn't notice. I will fix it and see if it works